# Composer is not functioning?

Tags: php, html, json, cmd, composer-php

I used composer install in the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpstormProjects, exactly where my website files are located. Now, when I want to view the local version of my files at `http://kabel.local.dev:8080`, I'm getting these errors:

`Warning: require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpstormProjects\www\index.php on line 14`

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpstormProjects\www\index.php on line 14`

I am probably using the wrong path but I'm not sure which path I should use? I tried **C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpstormProjects\vendor** but my cmd says that doesn't contain composer.json, the cmd tells me 
`No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpstormProjects? [Y,n]?`

Comment: Can you share your directory structure?

Comment: Ofcourse, this is my structure: http://prntscr.com/gzt5yi

Comment: And I presume your `index.php` is in the `www` folder? If that is the case, the `vendor` folder is **one directory up** (i.e. a sibling of the `www` folder), so you have to access it as such: `require_once('../vendor/autoload.php')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your vendor folder in `C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpstormProjects\` ?
If yes, you have to execute `composer update` in your `C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpstormProjects\www\` folder.

By default, you have to execute composer commands at the same location where your index.php is located.

OR you can change in your index.php the line

`require_once('vendor/autoload.php');`

to

`require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');`

Comment: Great answer, I think I've got it figured out now. It's installing.

Comment: This class does not exist. You can check if the package is listed in the composer.json. If THE PACKAGE is listed, check if it is also listed in autoload.php. If this isnt the case run composer install. After that it should be installed. You can also look for the class in the vendor folder which is maybe the easyer way to validate if the required class is in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.php file, try update the line 14 of

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

to

```
require_once('vendor'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php');
```

If this not work, please, send for us an picture for the folder structure or an snippet of your index.php

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply. I just tried that, did not work. Here's my index.php: http://prntscr.com/gzsu4n and here's my folder structure: http://prntscr.com/gzsuhx

Comment: Please, put this code below in your www/index.php and past here the value that be showed in your browser. Im trying debug value for the constant DOCUMENT_ROOT. You can do it?


After require_once('../config/bootstrap.php');, put this

`echo '<pre>';
echo 'DOCUMENT_ROOT:'.DOCUMENT_ROOT;
echo '</pre>';
exit();`

Comment: This is what I got when I placed that line behind the bootstrap.php line:
http://prntscr.com/gzt2ux

Comment: Ok, it was what i expected, the DOCUMENT_ROOT is empty. Now, try to replace the `require_once('vendor/autoload.php');` to `require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');`

Comment: Okay now I'm getting a 404, this is a pastebin of my index.php: https://pastebin.com/zvHATGXx

Comment: @MauricevanDorst, put this in the end of your bootstrap.php `if(!defined('DOCUMENT_ROOT'))
    define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));`

Comment: Okay I had to reset the index.php file to this: https://pastebin.com/ghtGvZTc, now I added **if(!defined('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));** but it won't help, I'm getting this right now: http://prntscr.com/gztdze. Could we continue in a chat? I can't setup one because my rep. is too low

Comment: My reputation too, i cant start a chat for now. But, the class AI\Lib\Log is of your application or a package installed by composer? Can you put here your composer.json.